# Empty a std::vector without change its size

Tags: c++, vector

I want to reuse a `std::vector` within a for loop. However, I need the vector to be empty for each iteration step of the for loop.

**Question:** How can I empty a vector rapidly without changing its capacity in the most efficient way?

What I used so far is

```
std::vector<int> myVec;
for(int i=0; i<A_BIG_NUMBER; ++i) {
    std::vector<T>().swap(myVec);
    myVec.reserve(STANDARD_MAXIMUM);

    /// .. doing business
}
```

Cheers!

**Solution:**

Thanks for the answers, here is how I implemented (checked) it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

 int main() {

    int n = 10;
    std::vector< int > myVec;
    myVec.reserve(n);
    for(int j=0; j<3; ++j) {
            myVec.clear();
            for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
                    myVec.push_back(i);
            }
            for(int i=0; i<myVec.size(); ++i) {
                    std::cout << i << ": " << myVec[i] << std::endl;
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** changed from `operator[]` to `push_back`.

Comment: Not only is the chosen solution wrong, the question doesn't even make sense.  If you want the vector's size to remain constant, you don't clear it.  You either just write over the top of existing elements, or reset each element individually.

Comment: @BoPersson: Yep, tricked myself. Wanted to get too much.. I'll take that snipped out of my question.

Comment: Were you looking for `remove` from the `algorithm` library?

Comment: @MrLister: Nope, thanks any way.

Comment: I tried the solution and it works on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: the author mixed capacity and size for the vector.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `vector::clear` method. It will clear the content without reducing its capacity.

Comment: Thanks, it's doing the job! +1

Comment: But it *will* reduce the size, making `myVec[i]=i;` above illegal.

Answer (score 5):

```
myVec.clear();
```

This is equivalent to `myVec.erase(myVec.begin(), myVec.end())`.

Answer (score 3):

To retain the current size of a vector with default values for its content, you can assign default values to the vector.  In the case of a vector of ints, you can do the following:

```
myVec.assign( myVec.size(), 0 );
```

Answer (score 2):

use clear method as below:

```
std::vector<int> myVec;
    for(int i=0; i<A_BIG_NUMBER; ++i) 
    {
        std::vector<T>().swap(myVec);
        myVec.reserve(STANDARD_MAXIMUM);

        /// .. doing business
    myVec.clear();
    }
```

Comment: Well, in this case he probably doesn't need his swap/reverse thing, does he?

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on OP's solution:
The normal approach for containers is to start with an empty container and fill it up as needed with an exception for std::vector where you can reserve space eventhough there are still no objects in the container.
If you want a different approach where an "empty container" would be a container of default objects that you can access like an array (only works with std::vector and std::deque), then you need to start with resize() and you can "clean up" with fill:

```
int n = 10;
std::vector<int> myVec;
myVec.resize(n);
myVec[4] = 5;
std::cout << myVec[4] << "\n";
std::fill(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), int()); // ofcourse for int, you can use 0 instead of int()
std::cout << myVec[4] << "\n";
```